# Pytorch beginner : tensor.new method

Tags: pytorch

everyone, I have a small question.

What is the purpose of the method `tensor.new(..)` in Pytorch, I didn't find anything in the documentation. It looks like it creates a new Tensor (like the name suggests), but why we don't just use `torch.Tensor` constructors instead of using this new method that requires an existing tensor.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the documentation of [tensor.new()](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/tensors.html?highlight=new#torch.Tensor.new) says:

> Constructs a **new** tensor of the same data type as **self** tensor.

Also note:

> For CUDA tensors, this method will create **new** tensor on the same device as this tensor.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that in the newer versions of PyTorch there are many of various `new_*` methods that are intended to replace this "legacy" `new` method.

So if you have some tensor `t = torch.randn((3, 4))` then you can construct a new one with the same type and device using one of these methods, depending on your goals:

```py
t = torch.randn((3, 4))
a = t.new_tensor([1, 2, 3])  # same type, device, new data
b = t.new_empty((3, 4))      # same type, device, non-initialized
c = t.new_zeros((2, 3))      # same type, device, filled with zeros
...
```

```py
for x in (t, a, b, c):
    print(x.type(), x.device, x.size())
# torch.FloatTensor cpu torch.Size([3, 4])
# torch.FloatTensor cpu torch.Size([3])
# torch.FloatTensor cpu torch.Size([3, 4])
# torch.FloatTensor cpu torch.Size([2, 3])
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple use-case and example using `new()`, since without this the utility of this function is not very clear.

Suppose you want to add Gaussian noise to a tensor (or Variable) without knowing a priori what it's datatype is.

This will create a tensor of Gaussian noise, the same shape and data type as a Variable `X`:

```
 noise_like_grad = X.data.new(X.size()).normal_(0,0.01)
```

This example also illustrates the usage of `new(size)`, so that we get a tensor of same type and same size as `X`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer. It is used to create a new tensor with the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The voted answers are right. And I want to add this:
I think from the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#tensors), we can't actually find the new method explanation. And I guess the reason if that this method is implemented by C, not by python.